# Printing pdf form access and secure it

Tags: ms-access, pdf, digital-signature, electronic-signature

Does anyone know if and how i can print a PDF from Access and secure it with a digital ID? I can print to PDF on buttonclick, but now i want to secure it in the same step. This means that i need to get up the Sign with digital ID box when i export to PDF form my access file, but how is that done?

I have the following working code for printing

```
    
Filnavn = mappe & Me.IDAarstallLNr & " DOC" & " - " & Replace(Now(), ":", "") & ".pdf"
Me.txtFilnavnDigitaltSignertPDF = mappe & Me.IDAarstallLNr & " Signed date " & Replace(Now(), ":", "") & ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, Rapportnavn, acFormatPDF, Filnavn, True, , acExportQualityScreen
If pfUserName() <> "SGR" Then Me.File_Dato_Mappe = Date
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: And what digital signing system are you planning to adopt? I think there is at a least what, 20 commercial vendors of such systems, and they all have different API's, different features, and some even require you to up-load the PDF to a web site. So, unless you picking a particular vendor of digital signing, then you question is similar to asking how long is a ball of string need to be? How you will achieve this goal will depend on the digital signing system you going to pick and choose.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, as i'm using the software i forgot to mention which software i'm using for the PDF. I'm using Adobe pro for signing my documents with a digital ID. At this point i do it manually meaning i print to a PDF and open the PDF after printing and sign it.